# Single Html Page without CMS (wordpress)

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a wordpress website (self hosted blog), but now I need to create a page like http://www.example.com/testpage.html.

How can I do this? How this person has done it? http://lukepeerfly.com/demos/iframe/html.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are few ways to a "landing page" in your site. here's 2 methods:

1 - you can create a page in the cms and then make a template for it.

For example, we wanna make a page named "landing". We duplicate the page.php file in our theme and change his name to landing.php (as described here: http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png).

Then, in the page's code, in the top, we'll write the template name in the right syntax:

```
< ?php
/*
Template Name: landing
*/
?>

//other html/php code here
```

You can include the header, footer, sidebar, or choose not to include them.
the page url will be `www.mysite.com/landing`.

2 - The second way is to create a file outside your theme folder, in your server's root directory or in some designated folder (using a ftp connection, ofcourse). in the example you brought, `http://lukepeerfly.com/demos/iframe/html.txt`, html.txt is probably located in **root\demos\iframe** directory on the server.

your new file will be outside the wordpress. if you do want the file to be a part of your wordpress system (you need it if you want to use wordpress functions, hooks, database and etc) you'll need to include the "wp-load.php" file in the start of your code.

For example, our page, "landing.php", is directory "pages" in my root directory. in the page's code we'll write the following lines:

```
<?php 
require('./../wp-load.php'); 
?>

//other html/php code here
```

In here as well, you can include the header, footer, sidebar, or choose not to include them.
the page url will be `www.mysite.com/pages/landing.php`.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can just create the .html file and upload it to your FTP server and then link to it in your wordpress blog.

Comment: How to like to WordPress blog?

Comment: just add a `<a href="http://myblog.com/myfile.html">link</a>` to whereever you want to link from ...